# Transfer learning with Inception-resnet-v2 neural network

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am using the following code to fit the Inception-resnet v2 pretrained model to perform transfer learning on my own dataset of images, with 8 classes.

I would like to know how I can remove the top layer and add a MaxPooling and dense softmax layer to do transfer learning on new images? similar to the Inception V3 code I use below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
slim = tf.contrib.slim
from PIL import Image
from inception_resnet_v2 import *
import numpy as np

checkpoint_file = 'inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt'

input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,299,299,3), name='input_image')
scaled_input_tensor = tf.scalar_mul((1.0/255), input_tensor)
scaled_input_tensor = tf.sub(scaled_input_tensor, 0.5)
scaled_input_tensor = tf.mul(scaled_input_tensor, 2.0)

# has to be scaled.
#im = 2*(im/255.0)-1.0

#Load the model
sess = tf.Session()
arg_scope = inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()
with slim.arg_scope(arg_scope):
  logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(scaled_input_tensor, is_training=True,num_classes=8,reuse=True,scope='InceptionResnetV2')
```

Inception V3 example:

```
output = InceptionV3_notop.get_layer(index = -1).output  # Shape: (8, 8, 2048)
output = AveragePooling2D((8, 8), strides=(1, 1), name='avg_pool')(output)
output = Flatten(name='flatten')(output)
output = Dense(8, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(output)
```